# Answers to questions but no acceptance or votes

Tags: support

I've been trying to work up a decent points score on [Super User](https://superuser.com), but it's very difficult. Not necessarily because I can't write answers, but because there seem to be a very high proportion of people who ask questions but either never come back, or who come back to see an answer but don't accept it or upvote it.

Example,

Activity - https://superuser.com/users/332907/roaima?tab=answers&sort=activity

Of 28 unaccepted answers in the last six months, 22 are where I'm the only person answering, and a fair number of those have no visible subsequent activity. Worse, others have interaction with the person asking the question but then they just head off into the night.

Is there a mechanism by which returning users are reminded to consider accepting answers to their past questions? (I've not seen one on [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com), where I tend to hang out more actively, but that doesn't necessarily mean there isn't one here.)

Assuming it's not just me, how do low-scoring users such as myself work up a reasonable score? Maybe it's just a symptom of a high-volume site like this one and I should move on elsewhere?

Comment: 1743 internet points is reasonable

Comment: @Burgi not when I'm comparing it to almost 80K

Comment: You don’t need answers to be accepted.  Most of my answers are never accepted but are typically the highest voted answers

Comment: @Ramhound, I want that 20K boundary. Heck, even the 2K threshold on this Stack would be a start. The issue as I see it isn't that a petulant user wants points, it's that there seems to be little inclination amongst swathes of the user base to award them

Comment: @roaima - I received a handful of bounties.  You don’t need them to have thousands of reputation.  Just answer hundreds of questions. If you answer 200 questions, and each Android only received 2 upvotes, that’s 2,000 reputation.

Comment: It’s actually 4,000 reputation (400 * 10).

Comment: Yeah I know. I'm an 80K user elsewhere.

Comment: To answer your question, users are indeed reminded to accept answers, if they have several questions without an accepted answer. You can't expect to have thousands of reputations with only 100 answers.  You have nearly 2,400 answers on Unix & Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You know these rep points can't be traded in for free snacks, right?

Sometimes the person asking the question just never comes back. Alternatively your answer might not solve their specific issue, therefore wouldn't deserve an acceptance tick or upvote.

I really wouldn't worry about it. Keep answering questions and helping people out. One day you will hit a question/answer that will go on the hot topic list and you'll hit the big time.